# Does Fairy Tail have one main goal / plot, or is it just many separate stories?

Tags: fairy-tail

Does Fairy Tail have one major plot line that is developed along the hundreds of episodes it has, or does it simply have many "chunks" of unrelated adventures (in blocks of a few episodes)?

For example, in One Piece there is one main "goal", and even though there are several different arcs, there is a clear notion of "progress towards the goal" happening with every arc. Naruto, Boku no Hero Academia and Black Clover also have clear "goals", i.e. there is also a main plot, and the "progress in the plot" is clear after every canon arc, etc.

I started watching Fairy Tail (only watched 15 episodes so far) and so far I couldn't see any "main plot" or "main goal". It seems that they will simply have different adventures, by picking certain quests/missions in the guild, fulfilling the mission, coming back and repeating this loop. Surely they will probably get stronger with time, but this is not the "progress" I'm looking for. Is there a "main goal", "main plot" that gets slowly developed along the hundreds of episodes? Or is it just a collection of loosely-tied adventures (each taking a few episodes each)?

**NOTE: Don't say what the main plot is (if it exists) - hide it in a spoiler tag. I just want to know if it exists - and if possible, what is the number of the episode in which this plot becomes clear.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking whether or not Fairy Tail is episodic, it is very much not. Similar to other Shonen series, it is broken up into a number of story arcs, with the first few being shorter in length and the later ones being much longer.

If watching the anime, there are a lot of extra episodic filler segments scattered between arcs, but those are technically not canon.

In terms of arcs themselves, around Episode 10 more substantial arcs appear (story arcs of at least 10 episodes), starting with Galuna, Phantom Lord, and the Tower of Heaven.

If there is a 'main plot', the first real introductory seeds (Dark Guids + Zeref, etc) are sown in the Oración Seis arc (according to the wiki, starts apx. Episode 52), but it's hard to pinpoint a 'main plot' until much later. There are more lighthearted arcs mixed in between the more serious arcs but generally speaking I'd consider things post-timeskip to be where things settle in on a main plot (albeit in a roundabout manner).

From the Tartaros Arc (Ep. 234) onwards, it's pretty much the 'highest stakes' portion of the series.

Comment: By episodic do you mean that each episode is a different story? I don't mean that, not every episode, but every block of 5-10 episodes. If you meant that too, then can you add an approximate episode number in which the fact that it is not episodic gets more clear? Also can you answer explicitly if Fairy Tail has one "goal" / main plot (and include what is it behind a spoiler tag)? Thanks! If you make these improvements I'll accept the answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately the last hundred chapters are where I lost interest in the series, and that constitutes an important part of the story. I've edited the question to add more information but I can't exactly phrase the 'main plot' of the series simply because I don't even remember what happened (it's been a few years). I hope my answer is more informative, even if it doesn't completely answer your question.